# Dynamic component loading based on type angular

Tags: angular, angular-components

Based on the type, I wanted to render component in angular.

For eg, with the below code, I wanted to render heading component dynamically.

```
{
 "type": "heading-1",
 "text": "Sample Text"
}
```

Below is the logic to render dynamic component

```
private renderReactiveContent(content: ContentDocument, container: ViewContainerRef) {

    // resolve content['_type'] to factory
    const type: Type<any> = this.contentMappings[content[0].type];
    if (!type) {
      throw new ReferenceError(`No content mapping for type=${content[0].type}`);
    }

    const componentFactory: ComponentFactory<any> = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(type);
    const component = container.createComponent(componentFactory, container.length, this.injector);
    console.info('Component dynamically created ', component);

    // content lifecycle hook: notify of new values
    const cmpCreate: ContentOnCreate = asContentCreate(component);
    cmpCreate.contentOnCreate(content);

    // render embedded content
    if (content && Object.keys(content).length > 0) {

      const cmpEmbeddable: ContentEmbeddable = asContentEmbeddable(component);
      if (cmpEmbeddable) {

        // render in the target element of ContentEmbeddable
        const childContainer = cmpEmbeddable.contentEmbeddable();

        Object.keys(content).forEach((key: string) => {
          const value = content[key];

          // XX: recursive rendering
          if (value instanceof Array) {
            value.forEach((v: ContentDocument) => {
              this.renderReactiveContent(v, childContainer);
            });
          } else {
            this.renderReactiveContent(value, childContainer);
          }
        });

      } else {

        // fatal: embedded content must be hosted by ContentEmbeddable
        const cmpName = component.instance['constructor'].name;
        throw new TypeError([`Trying to render embedded content.`,
          `${cmpName} must implement interface ContentEmbeddable`].join(' '));

      }

    }
    component.hostView.detectChanges();
  }
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, it's throws an error

`ERROR TypeError: Trying to render embedded content. HeadlineComponent must implement interface ContentEmbeddable`

I've created the stackblitz, project for reference please help.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7q1izn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as error is stating, your components must implement interface `ContentEmbeddable`. You can do it like this (for every component you want to create dynamically):

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewContainerRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ContentOnCreate, ContentEmbeddable } from '../../render/content.interfaces';

@Component({
  selector: 'rc-headline',
  template: `<h1>{{ text }}</h1>`
})
export class HeadlineComponent implements OnInit, ContentOnCreate, ContentEmbeddable {
  @Input()
  public text: string;

  constructor(private containerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  contentOnCreate(values: { [key: string]: any; }): void {
    this.text = values.text;
  }

  contentEmbeddable(): ViewContainerRef {
    return this.containerRef;
  }

}
```

But project will still throwing error:

```
No content mapping for type=undefined
```

Replacing this:

```
const type: Type<any> = this.contentMappings[content[0].type];
if (!type) {
  throw new ReferenceError(`No content mapping for type=${content[0].type}`);
}
```

With this:

```
var type: Type<any>;
if (content instanceof Array) {
  type = this.contentMappings[content[0].type];
} else {
  type = this.contentMappings[content.type];
}
if (!type) {
  return;
  // throw new ReferenceError(`No content mapping for type=${type}`);
}
```

In `content-host.component.ts` file  (`renderReactiveContent` method) will fix the error and you should see sample heading and three paragraphs rendered.
See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4tnear) demo with working solution.